# Why do we have to set a width with margin : 0 auto when horizontally centering a div?

Tags: css, margin, centering

Why do we have to use a set width when using `margin:0 auto;` to center a div horizontally?

Comment: You don't have to, unless you're trying to center the element horizontally.

Comment: margin:0 auto; means that top and bottom margins are 0 while
right and left margins are auto. "auto" isn't related with 0.

Comment: Because if there isn't a width, then the width is 100% which can't be centered.

Answer (score 3):

If the element is `display: block`, and you don't set a width, the element will [stretch horizontally to fit its containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth), causing the auto margins to be zeroed out (which, technically, counts as centering the element since both auto margins resolve to an equal value of zero).

Comment: My bad, I forgot to specifiy that was about horizontally centering a div

Comment: @Radioreve, the answer is still correct.